# Teams App : Is it mandatory that customer should have 365 to use teams app?

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-teams

Is it mandatory that the tenant has to have Microsoft Office 365? Can we sync our on premise Active Directory to Azure AD using Azure Connect and login to Microsoft Teams using AD credentials?

Answer (score 1):

the Full version of teams requires an office 365 license. as this is an office 365 product. 
Without an office 365 license that includes teams. you won't be able to use the full version of teams regardless of AD Account. 
So to answer your question. yes it is mandatory to have a o365/teams license in order to use teams.

There is however a free version of teams that you can use, and if your entire tenant in aad doesn't have any office 365 at all, then 'I believe' you can log into / sign up for that free version. 
though there are various limitations on that version but if you are just testing it out, or are a small organization, of less than 25 users then you could use it.